# Parallelize a RDD variable expected from an external file in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Based on the materials I read and some online posts, I think Spark will broadcast all a RDD variable from external file by: `sc.textFile`, for example:

`val rdd = sc.textFile(file_path)`

however, when my colleague read my code and requests me code with `sc.parallelize`, I am so confused about it as i think the `sc.parallelize` is redundant, I asked my colleague again and he gave me a answer:

To my experience up till now, spark doesn't good at handling the dividence of external file over multiple nodes and workers, so you need set partitions, forcing the worker to apply multiple workers to do the job.

So based on my colleague's suggestions, what is the easiest way that I can set partitions when I am reading a large volume file if `sc.textFile` can not do that. A possible way is to `collect` first and then `sc.parallelize`, but i think it wast too much time and it is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call rdd.repartion(..). Collect and parrallelise is not the right way to achieve what you describe.

The reason that your colleague observed this behaviour is probably due to small files, as partitioning is driven by the HDFS blocks when reading. So if you files are smaller than the block size, all your data will end up in the same executor.